# How to disable time sync in a VMware shared folder?

Tags: date, vmware, vmware-workstation

My Windows 10 desktop has VMware. To set past time in VMware, I disabled sync options as described here: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1189

I just tried to set the date to past time in VMware. And it worked.

However, after reading and writing files in a shared directory within Linux (VMware), the time is synced to the current time. How can I disable the time and date sync in the VMware shared folder?

p.s: VMware version is VMware Workstation 16 Player, and Linux is CentOS 5.0.

Comment: You may know - you cant

Answer (score 1):

If time sync is disabled with VMware tools as the KB you linked, then there is something else that is syncing the time. You can verify if the VMware timesync running the following in the guest `vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync status`
If you haven't, try checking if the NTP service is running.
https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/centos5/centos5_administration_guide/centos5_s1-dateconfig-ntp.html